# How to get the last timestamp for a given date?

Tags: mysql

I have a timestamp column in my table. I want to pass a date as a paramater and run a search which returns the final row for that day (MAX timestamp, given the :date parameter).

My query currently looks like

```
SELECT some columns
FROM table_1
JOIN table_2 ON column_name
```

and I want to add a `WHERE times_stamp` something `:date` something  something ... I'm stuck.

What is my where clause ?

The first part of the search is exceedingly complex, but works, so I won't bother with it here, nor with the data, since it is not relevant; just know that there is a`time_stamp` column and I want the final one for a given date..

I think that I am looking at soemthing like

`WHERE DATE(t.time_stamp) = :date ORDER BY p.time_stamp DESC LIMIT 1`

but I just don't know how to formulate it.

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: it should be `WHERE t.time_stamp >= :date AND t.time_stamp < :date + INTERVAL 1 DAY` so it will use `INDEX` if you have defined one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT some_columns
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.column_name = t2.column_name
where date(times_stamp) = :date
order by times_stamp desc
limit 1
```

Comment: `where WHERE times_stamp = :date` please change it

Comment: are you sure you don' mean `where DATE(timestamp) = :date` ?